# CakePHP Email Component check if email was sent

Tags: email, cakephp

I am just wondering how can you check if email was sent or it failed whenever using the EmailComponent in CakePHP?

For example I currently use it this way:

```
$this->Email->from='<xyz@yahoo.com>';  
$this->Email->to='<abc@gmail.com>';
$this->Email->sendAs='both';
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
$this->Email->send();
```

Comment: To get correct answers you *always* need to provide the cakephp version you are working with!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$this->Email->send()` *should* return true if it was sent successfully. You could try something like:

```
if ( $this->Email->send() ) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Reference:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-EmailComponent.html

Note: If you're using CakePHP 2.x you might try using the CakeEmail class instead; EmailComponent is deprecated ([Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)). If you're using 1.x then carry on. :p

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments, if you *are* using 2.x you should keep in mind that CakeEmail (which is used by EmailComponent) can throw an exception. You can handle it with [CakePHP itself](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) or by tossing in a try/catch:

```
try {
    if ( $this->Email->send() ) {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Failure, without any exceptions
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // Failure, with exception
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this need a try catch block? Since it can throw exceptions... The documentation states: "We recommend to you use try/catch to ensure your messages are delivered correctly."

Comment: @mark could you point to the documentation for that? You may have a valid point, but I couldn't find that. The EmailComponent itself doesn't seem to be throwing exceptions by itself if I look inside the source.

Comment: The email component just wraps the send() of CakeEmail which does. Therefore it also throws exceptions and would create quite some trouble if not catched properly. Its also on here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/email.html

Comment: Yep, CakeEmail can throw a SocketException exception if you don't set any of the necessary properties. However, if the OP is using 1.x, EmailComponent obviously won't use CakeEmail. For 2.x I usually just let Cake handle any exceptions for me with a custom exception handler, but using try/catch is certainly a good idea. I'll update my answer to point that out. Thanks Mark.

Comment: I believe I tried that and didn't work however I'll try it again I am sure I've messed up smth else. Thanks