# Checking if an email was send using CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to check whether the email has been sent or not. (in case the email is incorrect, or the server is down... or whatever)

As the [Email component is deprecated](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-EmailComponent.html), now the value returned by `send()` is not a boolean anymore [but an array with string messages.](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeEmail.html#_send)

How can I check it now?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that it now properly throws an Exception if something goes really wrong. Beyond that, you cannot really check if the email was incorrect, for example. It will send successfully but just bounce back some time later. You would need to have a bounce-inbox and pop/imap php classes to fetch and process those.

Comment: Steve: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15649687/265575) for more details.